# How to plot a dot plot type scatterplot in matplotlib or seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter, dot-plot

Let's say I have a df like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('aabbb'), 'col2': [1, 3, 1, 5, 3]})

  col1  col2
0    a     1
1    a     3
2    b     1
3    b     5
4    b     3
```

I would like to see a plot, where on the x axis, I have the col1 names ONCE, and on the y axis, the col2 data, as individual dots, so above 'a' I would have two dots at the height of 1 and 3, and above b I would have three dots at the heights of 1, 5 and 3.
My main problem is that anything I try results in several a and b on the x axis, not grouped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beeswarm, strip, and scatter plots are all options, depending on your data and preferred aesthetic.

---

#### [`plt.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) or [`df.plot.scatter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) (most basic)

```
plt.scatter(data=df, x='col1', y='col2') # or df.plot.scatter(x='col1', y='col2')
plt.margins(x=0.5)
```

[image]

---

#### [`sns.swarmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html) (avoid collisions)

```
sns.swarmplot(data=df, x='col1', y='col2')
```

[image]

---

#### [`sns.stripplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html) (random jitter)

```
sns.stripplot(data=df, x='col1', y='col2')
```

[image]